# Flutter model for nested json object

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter. I have tried to developed  Model class in dart. but always show the error message

```
Exception:type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String', tt:#0      new User.fromJson
```

I don't understand, where my code will error. I want to solutions.

I want to convert model class in dart.

```
[
    {
        "route": {
            "routeID": "aaaaaaaa",
            "routeTitle": "bbbbbbbb"
        },
        "distributor": {
            "distributorID": "cccccccccccc",
            "distributorName": "ddddddddddd"
        },
        "visitDate": null
    }
]
```

I have been tried to my source code. like below code

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> userFromJson(String str) =>
    List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(List<User> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class User {
  User({
    this.visitDate,
    this.route,
    this.distributor,
  });

  String visitDate;
  String route;
  String distributor;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    visitDate: json["visitDate"],
    route: json["route"],
    distributor: json["distributor"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "visitDate": visitDate,
    "route": route,
    "distributor": distributor,
  };
}

Route RouteFromJson(String str) => Route.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String RouteToJson(Route data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Route {
  Route({
    this.routeID,
    this.routeTitle,
  });

  String routeID;
  String routeTitle;

  factory Route.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Route(
    routeID: json["routeID"],
    routeTitle: json["routeTitle"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "routeID": routeID,
    "routeTitle": routeTitle,
  };
}
Distributor DistributorFromJson(String str) => Distributor.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String DistributorToJson(Distributor data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class Distributor {
  Distributor({
    this.distributorID,
    this.distributorName,
  });

  String distributorID;
  String distributorName;

  factory Distributor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Distributor(
    distributorID: json["distributorID"],
    distributorName: json["distributorName"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "distributorID": distributorID,
    "distributorName": distributorName,
  };
}
```

how to correct my model class. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your User class like this :

```
 class User {
      User({
        this.visitDate,
        this.route,
        this.distributor,
      });
    
      String visitDate;
      Route route;
      Distributor distributor;
    
      factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        visitDate: json["visitDate"],
        route = json['route'] != null ? Route.fromJson(json['route']) : null;
        distributor = json['distributor'] != null
            ? Distributor.fromJson(json['distributor'])
            : null;
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "visitDate": visitDate,
        if (route != null) {
          data['route'] = this.route.toJson();
        }
        if (distributor != null) {
          data['distributor'] = this.distributor.toJson();
        }
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the `json_serializable` package for that.
This way, you don't have to write this code yourself.

https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Box.!

You just need to do simple job is to visit following website. And need to put your response or map/list that you want to convert in model class and rest will be done by server.

By the way,
For your List<Map<String, dynamic> data's model class is,

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final routeModelClass = routeModelClassFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<RouteModelClass> routeModelClassFromJson(String str) => List<RouteModelClass>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => RouteModelClass.fromJson(x)));

String routeModelClassToJson(List<RouteModelClass> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class RouteModelClass {
    RouteModelClass({
        this.route,
        this.distributor,
        this.visitDate,
    });

    Route route;
    Distributor distributor;
    dynamic visitDate;

    factory RouteModelClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RouteModelClass(
        route: Route.fromJson(json["route"]),
        distributor: Distributor.fromJson(json["distributor"]),
        visitDate: json["visitDate"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "route": route.toJson(),
        "distributor": distributor.toJson(),
        "visitDate": visitDate,
    };
}

class Distributor {
    Distributor({
        this.distributorId,
        this.distributorName,
    });

    String distributorId;
    String distributorName;

    factory Distributor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Distributor(
        distributorId: json["distributorID"],
        distributorName: json["distributorName"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "distributorID": distributorId,
        "distributorName": distributorName,
    };
}

class Route {
    Route({
        this.routeId,
        this.routeTitle,
    });

    String routeId;
    String routeTitle;

    factory Route.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Route(
        routeId: json["routeID"],
        routeTitle: json["routeTitle"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "routeID": routeId,
        "routeTitle": routeTitle,
    };
}
```

[List/Map to Model class](https://app.quicktype.io/)